# IIS Competing with CodeReady Containers

Tags: openshift, redhat-containers

I have Windows 10 Pro and have installed CodeReady Containers (with "user" network mode due to being on VPN).  When I initially do "crc setup" to create the virtual machine, it works fine, and "crc start" works as does "crc console".  However, if I restart my computer, the console URL https://console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing/ unexpectedly shows the IIS "welcome page".  I've tried navigating to IIS, right-clicking my localhost server and clicking "Stop", but still the "welcome page" displays.  If I open a CLI and execute "iisreset /STOP", when I navigate to the crc console URL, Chrome shows "This site can't be reached / ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".  Also if I try to execute "crc stop" I see an error:

dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2222: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Also "crc status" shows: OpenShift: Unreachable (v4.8.2)

I need to be able to have IIS coexisting with CodeReady Containers, ideally with both running simultaneously.  How can I make this happen?  There must be something with the initial crc setup that allows the console URL to work.

Comment: I tried adding a firewall rule to open port 2222, and also tried setting up a new vEthernet switch and nat based on this guide https://giritharan.com/configure-hyper-v-to-use-the-wireless-in-a-windows-10-computer/ and updating the config.json to supply the new IP and switch name, but neither attempt resulted in any changes.

Comment: I was previously using CodeReady Containers 4.8.2 from a download on GitHub.  After downloading the Windows installer from RedHat's site (login required), and upgrading to 4.8.4, I didn't have the same connectivity issues, but I still need to disable IIS so that it won't compete.  There must be a setting somewhere to run CodeReady Containers on different ports than 80 and 443.

Comment: I found this regarding Apache blocking 'crc start' due to using port 443 similar to IIS: https://github.com/code-ready/crc/issues/2613.  It sounds like there's currently no way to change crc's startup port easily.